# Как поставить пробел через каждый символ в строке

Tags: c#

Допустим дана строка "Hello World", мне нужно получить строку "H e l l o  W o r l d"
Как я это могу сделать в C#?

Comment: А вместо пробела между словами должно стать два пробела или один?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вместо пробела между словами должен быть только один пробел, а не два, то так:

```
string test = "Hello world";

test = test.Replace(" ", string.Empty);            
var result = String.Join(" ", test.ToCharArray());

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Если вместо пробела делать два пробела (то есть считать его таким же равноправным символом, как и буквы в строке), то просто надо будет закоментировать строку

```
test = test.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
```

[Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) - Возвращает новую строку, в которой все вхождения заданной строки в текущем экземпляре заменены другой заданной строкой.

[ToCharArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx) - разбивает строку на `char` массив

[Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tk0xe5h0(v=vs.110).aspx) - Сцепляет указанные элементы массива строк, помещая между ними заданный разделитель.

Comment: Можно просто скастить: http://ideone.com/xScYru

Comment: @VladD не знал, до сегодня)

Answer (score 3):

Можно регуляркой:

```
string input = "Hello World";
 var result = Regex.Replace(input, "(.)", "$1 ");
```

Можно перебором:

```
string input = "Hello World";
 StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
 foreach (var chr in input)
   {
      result.Append(chr+ " ");
    }
        result = result.ToString().TrimEnd();
```

Еще можно через LINQ:

```
   string input = "Hello World";
   string result = string.Join("", input.Select(x => x + " "));
```

Comment: в цикле тип result лучше изменить на StringBuilder и использовать метод Append(). В текущем виде цикл будет генерить тонны мусорных строк.

Comment: @rdorn, да, действительно. Поправил.